# Angular - @Output not working

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to use `@Output` directive to notify parent component when a button is clicked on child component. Following is my code:

**parent view**

```
<app-perito-select *ngIf="peritoSelect" (cancel)="cancelPeritoAction()"></app-perito-select>
```

**parent controller**

```
...
cancelPeritoAction(){
    console.log('cancel inside parent');
    this.selectedAction = undefined;
  }
```

**child controller**

```
...
@Output() cancelAction: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();  
...
cancel(){
    console.log('cancel inside child');
    this.cancelAction.emit();
  }
```

I followed [this](https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2#stateful-parent-component-binding) tutorial and it seems pretty straightforward, but I don't reach the parent function. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing

```
(cancel)="cancelPeritoAction()"
```

with

```
(cancelAction)="cancelPeritoAction()"
```

because name of your @Output event is `cancelAction`

Answer (score 2):

You can rename your external Output property by adding it as a string parameter if you want to keep (cancel) as the usage:

```
@Output('cancel') cancelAction: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```